# Browse Button with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, canvas

I want to add an image in canvas by using browse button. I tried to do something, I can use browse button but not add an image in canvas.How can I do?

```
<div style="float:left;"><canvas id="c" width="800" height="800"></canvas></div>
<p onclick="jQuery('#file').trigger('click');">Select a file</p>
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript to add the image to your canvas element?

Comment: Input type of file has a lot of security restrictions around it. JavaScript will be unable to access any value you put into it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#file-input').change(function(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0],
            imageType = /image.*/;

        if (!file.type.match(imageType))
            return;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = loadFile;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    });

    function loadFile(e) {
        var $img = $('<img>', { src: e.target.result });
        var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        $img.load(function() {
            context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        });
    }
});
</script>
<div style="float:bottom"><input type="file" id="file-input"><div>
<div style="float:left">
<canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="800px"></canvas>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks I can upload image but how can I fit in image in canvas?

Comment: That’s what it does. When you upload an image, the image is displayed in the Canvas. I have made a JSFiddle you can look at: http://jsfiddle.net/n6end8v5/